# Логическая ошибка при использовании .setNotifyOnChange(true);

Tags: android

в идеале написано, что при изменении `ArrayList` происходит обновление адаптера спиннера, в моем случае данные берутся из базы - помещаются в `ArrayList`- используются адаптером спиннера , то есть, `ArrayList` обновляется только при открытии активити. Понимаю, что надо вставить это обновление в обработчик кнопки, но оно туда никак вставать не хочет, а возможно я вообще иду не по верному пути?

Возможно есть варианты, например, забивать спиннер прямо из базы, без посредников, либо еще проще варианты?

и так код:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_resh = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data_resh);
adapter_resh.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_resh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.resh_list);
adapter_resh.setNotifyOnChange(true);
spinner_resh.setAdapter(adapter_resh);
```

Comment: Да, наполнять прямо из БД через SimpleCursorAdapter или его наследника, для нестандартного вида.

Comment: Так же неплохо было бы следовать конвенции Java в части именования экземпляров классов

Comment: почитаю про  конвенцию Java в части именования экземпляров классов